# Bison reduce/reduce conflicts syntax analysis

Tags: c, bison

I'm trying to compile and run code in Bison with the command `bison -d comp.y` on Linux, but I get the message: `comp.y: warning: 1 reduce/reduce conflict [-Wconflicts- rr]` and I don't know what to do, I'm not familiar with bison so I'm pretty lost.
The content of `cabecalho.h` is:

#define YYSTYPE double
extern YYSTYPE yylval

Here is the code from the comp.y file:

```
%{
#include "cabecalho.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern int linhas;
extern int erros;
%}

%token ASPAS ABRE_PARENTESIS FECHA_PARENTESIS
%token ABRE_CHAVE FECHA_CHAVE SEPARADOR VIRGULA
FLOAT INT PRINTF VOID DOUBLE LONG MAIN
%token IDENTIFICADOR INTEIRO REAL OPERADOR
COMPARADORES NEGACAO IGUAL
%token ATRIBUICAO
%start Programa_principal

%%

Programa_principal: MAIN ABRE_PARENTESIS
FECHA_PARENTESIS ABRE_CHAVE Comandos
FECHA_CHAVE | error {yyerror("", linhas); };

Comandos: Comando Comandos | Comando | ;

Comando: Declaracao | Atribuicao | Print | error {yyerror("command error",linhas); };

Declaracao: Tipo Decl SEPARADOR;

Tipo: INT | FLOAT | DOUBLE | LONG INT ;

Decl: LISTA_VAR ;

LISTA_VAR: IDENTIFICADOR Atribui_valor VIRGULA LISTA_VAR | IDENTIFICADOR Atribui_valor;

Atribui_valor: IGUAL Num | ;

Num: INTEIRO | REAL ;


Atribuicao: IDENTIFICADOR IGUAL Exp SEPARADOR ;

Exp: INT x | FLOAT x | Num x | IDENTIFICADOR x;

x: OPERADOR Exp | ;


Print: PRINTF ABRE_PARENTESIS ASPAS
Qualquer_palavra ASPAS FECHA_PARENTESIS
SEPARADOR;

Qualquer_palavra: IDENTIFICADOR y;

y: IDENTIFICADOR y | ;

%%

FILE *yyin;

int yyerror(char *str, int num_linha) {
if(strcmp(str,"syntax error")==0){
erros++;
printf("Syntactic error\n");
}
else
{
printf("Error at line %d\n",num_linha);
}
return erros;
}

main (int argc, char **argv )
{
++argv, --argc;
if ( argc > 0 )
yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
else
{
puts("failed to open file");

exit(0);
}
do {

yyparse();

} while (!feof(yyin));
if(erros==0)
puts("Success!");

}
```

I really don't understand where it is and what the indicated error is.

Comment: Please don't show screen shots — especially of messages that are text messages.  Include the message in the question as 'code'.  Indeed, you've included the message; you could include the compile command line (`bison -d comp.y`) in the question.  What's in `"cabelcalho.h"`?  And it's a good idea to indent your code for consistency and readability.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips Jonathan, I'll fix the problems.

Comment: To find out more about the reduce/reduce error, you need to add the `-v` option to the command line and study the `y.output` file (or `comp.output`, probably).

Comment: To find out if it is necessary to show the header, try compiling the code without the header.  If it produces the same message (give or take the line number, if any), then the header was not necessary.  Removing unnecessary code is part of creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: Note that you should not be writing code for C89, and your code is only valid in C89 because `main(int argc, char **argv)` has no explicit `int` return type that is required by C99 or later.  But you can probably omit all the code after the second `%%` without altering the Bison error message.

Comment: There are a lot of rules with an empty alternative (`| ;`).  One or more of those is likely the cause of the trouble.  The reduce/reduce conflict occurs on rules 3 and 4 — `3 Comandos: Comando . Comandos` and `4 | Comando .` on symbol `FECHACHAVE`.

Comment: I compiled it without the header and the error remained. I will remove it.